# Error reusing some async json method on windows phone

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

**EDIT 1:** *I added below the code who calls and uses the second method, and the error and data I recive*

First of all sorry if my English isn't good enough, and sorry if there is another thread with the solution. I haven't found it.

Ok, I'm making a windows phone 8 app that uses a lot of info from a web service. The app makes different Json Post and uses the info. I maked a method for Posting that WORKS:

```
    public static async void checkdeviceid()
    {
        //Where we are posting to:
        Uri theUri = new Uri("urlofexample");

        //Create an Http client
        HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
        //Class that will be serialized into Json
        objetoslistas.checkdeviceidinput paquete = new objetoslistas.checkdeviceidinput();
        //Set some values
        paquete.Text = "deviceID";
        paquete.Text2 = App.device_id;
        //serialize data
        var serializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paquete);
        //Post the data
        HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paquete), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string res = await aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var respuestaperfil = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objetoslistas.checkdeviceidoutput>(res.ToString());
            //Do something with the data
        }
        else
        {
            // show the response status code
            String failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " - Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase;
        } 
    }
```

This code its actually working, but the fact it's that my app will have maybe 30 or 40 diferent POST, so I tried to make a reusable method like this:

```
public static async Task<string> jsonPOST(Uri theUri, object paquete)
    {

        //Create an Http client and set the headers we want
        HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();

        //serialize data
        var serializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paquete);


        //Post the data
        HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paquete), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string res = await aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return res;
        }
        else
        {
            // show the response status code
            String failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " - Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase;
            return failureMsg;
        } 
    }
```

This code gives me problems in the main, were it's called. As I can understand, the problem is that, as the method calls some await process, the rest of the code continues with the execution without expect for the await result...

The code in Main is:

```
        objetoslistas.checkdeviceidinput paquete = new objetoslistas.checkdeviceidinput();
        paquete.Text = "deviceID";
        paquete.Text2 = App.device_id;
        Uri url = new Uri("urlofhteservice");
        Task<string> recibo = metodosJson.jsonPOST(url, paquete);
        var respuestaperfil = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objetoslistas.checkdeviceidoutput>(recibo.ToString);
        if (respuestaperfil.Text2 == null)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["DeviceRegistered"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["DeviceRegistered"] = false;
        }
```

And I recive this error (translated from google translator, sorry)

```
There was an exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but not controlled in the user code
```

The data I have in "recibo" is

```
        recibo  Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>
```

So as I understand the await method is still waiting.

Was I clear?
Thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. `This code gives me problems in the main` What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the code in Main continues without expecting for the result of the post. As I deserialize in the Main becaus I need to say the specific object for each Post, it says the result is not valid for deserialice.

Comment: As you can see, We miss the code where you call this method and the exception you get. How about posting more code and the complete error message?

Comment: I edited the code with the info you ask for

Comment: Now change `Task<string> recibo = metodosJson.jsonPOST(url, paquete);` to `string recibo = await metodosJson.jsonPOST(url, paquete);` I guess it will work...

Comment: IT WORKS. THANK YOU!!!! If you anytime come to Alicante-spain send me a private I Invite you to a drink ^_^